# encoding and storage of IVs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, character-encoding

I'm using Ruby's standard OpenSSL library. It has a method called `random_iv` that generates an IV with the proper length in `ASCII-8BIT` (binary) encoding. However, my Rails app and database is configured for UTF-8. I can't convert that to UTF-8 to store it (because it's binary, not ASCII text). So, how do I go about it? Do I have to do base64 conversion? Use `SecureRandom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the data in a `:binary` or `:blob` column? These are designed to store arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Makes sense. I knew I was overcomplicating things out of confusion.

Comment: ActiveRecord uses only `:binary` as a possible type for this.